# Ecplipse ANT build error

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm new with ANT build, and I have a trouble with it, when I try to build I'm receiving a message:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\user\Documents\PM\proyecto-base\proyecto-base\intranet\build.xml:169: Reference xdoclet.classpath not found.

but I have xdoclet.classpath declared already in the same file.

Also I have the properties like ${xdoclet.lib.dir} declared in a build.properties file.

here's my build.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!-- Ant Build File para Intranet -->
<project name="${project.name}" default="ear" basedir=".">

    <!-- Importar funcionalidad comun -->
    <import file="../common.xml" />
    <property name="jboss.security-domain" value="java:/jaas/NotificacionApplicationSecurity" />
    <target name="init">        
        <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="${hibernate.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="${hibernate-annotations.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="${sri-adm.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="${sri-seguridad.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="${jsf.dir}" />
            <fileset file="${servicio.jar}" />
            <fileset file="${log4j.jar}" />
            <fileset file="${servlet.jar}" />
            <fileset file="${mail.jar}" />
            <fileset dir="${jboss.lib}">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <path id="xdoclet.classpath">
            <fileset dir="${xdoclet.lib.dir}" />
            <pathelement location="${j2ee.jar}" />
            <pathelement location="${servlet.jar}" />
        </path>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" depends="init">
        <delete dir="../${build.dir}/intranet" />
        <delete dir="../${dist.dir}">
            <exclude name="${servicio.name}-${version}.jar"/>
        </delete>
    </target>


    <!--=============== Compile JAVA files ========================-->
    <target name="compile" description="Compile" >
        <echo message="Start compilation..." />
        <!-- compile project-->
        <mkdir dir="../${build.intranet.dir}/classes"/>
        <javac destdir="../${build.intranet.dir}/classes" target="1.5" debug="true" deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
            <src path="${src.main.java.dir}" />
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!--============== Genera archivos web==========-->
    <target name="webdoclet" description="Generar archivos XML Web y Struts" >
        <echo message="Generando Web" />
        <delete file="../${metadata.intranet.web.dir}/jboss-web.xml"/>
            <webdoclet destdir="../${metadata.intranet.web.dir}" force="${xdoclet.force}" mergedir="${conf.xdoclet.intranet.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${src.main.java.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.java" />
                </fileset>
                <deploymentdescriptor displayname="SRI" description="" xmlencoding="ISO-8859-1" 
                    validatexml="true" servletspec="2.4" sessiontimeout="60" destdir="../${metadata.intranet.web.dir}" 
                    mergeDir="../${conf.xdoclet.intranet.dir}" distributable="false" />

                <facesconfigxml destinationfile="${project.name}-faces-config.xml" mergedir="../${metadata.intranet-jsf}" />
                <jbosswebxml
                    version="4.0"
                    mergeDir="${metadata.intranet-jbossweb}"
                    contextroot="${project.name}"
                    securitydomain="${jboss.security-domain}"
                    validateXML="true" xmlencoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
            </webdoclet>
            <replace file="../${metadata.intranet.web.dir}/jboss-web.xml" token="&lt;security-domain" value="&lt;security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation=&quot;true&quot;" />        

    </target>



    <target name="build" depends="init,webdoclet" description="Compila las clases">
        <mkdir dir="../${classes.dir}" />
        <javac destdir="../${classes.dir}" debug="on" deprecation="on" optimize="off" target="1.5" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
            <src path="${src.main.java.dir}" />
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
            <classpath refid="xdoclet.classpath" />

            <!-- Descomentar si se quieren ver los Warnings -->
            <!--compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" /-->
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!--=============  Genera un archivo WAR del proyecto =============================-->

    <target name="war" description="Packages app as WAR" depends="compile, webdoclet">
        <echo message="Generando WAR..." />
        <mkdir dir="../${dist.dir}/intranet" />
        <copy todir="../${metadata.tmp.intranet.dir}">
            <fileset dir="../${metadata.intranet.web.dir}" />
            <filterset>
                <filter token="project.name" value="${project.name}"/>
            </filterset>
        </copy>
        <copy file="../${conf.intranet.dir}/jboss-web.xml" todir="../${metadata.tmp.intranet.dir}">
            <filterset>
                <filter token="project.name" value="${project.name}"/>
            </filterset>
        </copy> 

        <war destfile="../${dist.dir}/intranet/${webapp.intranet.name}.war" webxml="../${metadata.intranet.web.dir}/web.xml">
            <classes dir="../${build.intranet.dir}/classes">
                <include name="**/**/controladores/*.*"/>
                <include name="**/**/web/**/*.*"/>
                <include name="**/**/validadores/**/*.*"/>
                <include name="**/**/convertidores/**/*.*"/>
                <exclude name="**/**/internet/**/*.*"/>
            </classes>
            <classes dir="../intranet/src/main/java">
                <include name="**/**/*.properties"/>
            </classes>
            <fileset dir="${src.main.webapp.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*" />
            </fileset>

            <lib dir="${jsf.dir}" >
                <include name="rich*.jar" />
                <include name="jsf*facelet*.jar" />
            </lib>
            <lib dir="${sri-seguridad.dir}" >
                <include name="seguridad*.jar" />
            </lib>


            <lib dir="${lib.dir}" >
                <include name="commons-digester.jar" />
                <include name="commons-beanutils.jar" />
                <include name="commons-fileupload.jar" />
                <include name="commons-el.jar" />
                <include name="commons-lang-2.1.jar" />
            </lib>

            <!-- Archivos de configuracion en WEB-INF -->
            <webinf file="../${metadata.tmp.intranet.dir}/web.xml" />
            <webinf file="../${metadata.tmp.intranet.dir}/${project.name}-faces-config.xml" />
            <webinf file="../${metadata.tmp.intranet.dir}/jboss-web.xml" />
        </war>
        <delete dir="../${metadata.tmp.intranet.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="ear" depends="war">
        <mkdir dir="../${metadata.intranet-ejb.tmp}" />
        <copy todir="../${metadata.intranet-ejb.tmp}">
            <fileset dir="../${metadata.intranet-ejb}" />
            <filterset>
                <filter token="project.name" value="${project.name}"/>
                <filter token="intranet.name" value="${intranet.name}"/>
            </filterset>
        </copy> 
        <ear destfile="../${dist.dir}/intranet/${webapp.intranet.name}.ear" appxml="../${metadata.intranet-ejb.tmp}/application.xml">
            <fileset dir="../${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="../${dist.dir}/intranet" includes="*.war"/>

        </ear>
        <delete dir="../${metadata.intranet-ejb.tmp}" />
    </target>


    <target name="deploy" depends="ear" description="Copia el archivo WAR en el directorio deploy del server">
        <copy file="../${dist.dir}/intranet/${webapp.intranet.name}.ear" todir="${jboss.deploy.intranet.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Definición de WebDoclet -->
    <taskdef name="webdoclet" classname="xdoclet.modules.web.WebDocletTask">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="xdoclet.classpath" />
            <path refid="classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>



    <!-- Definicion de JSF -->

    <taskdef name="facesconfigxml" classname="xdoclet.modules.jsf.FacesConfigXmlSubTask">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="xdoclet.classpath" />
            <path refid="classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>  
</project>
```

the lines which are returning me the error are the following:

```
<!-- Definición de WebDoclet -->
<taskdef name="webdoclet" classname="xdoclet.modules.web.WebDocletTask">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="xdoclet.classpath" />
        <path refid="classpath" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

but as I told you I have already declared my xdoclet.classpath in the same file at the begining:

```
 <path id="xdoclet.classpath">
            <fileset dir="${xdoclet.lib.dir}" />
            <pathelement location="${j2ee.jar}" />
            <pathelement location="${servlet.jar}" />
        </path>
```

Can Anyone help me with this Issue please? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your path definition is inside of the the target "init", but the taskdef definition is outside of any target up at the project level.  When ant loads the build file, it's going to try validating everything that is defined at the project level.  In this case it fails becuase the init target has not run yet and the xdoclet.classpath path is not defined.

If you just move the path element out to the project level like the taskdef is, the issue should go away.